# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class { have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-fragmentactivity, insert-update

I'm having these error

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
>           at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:791)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:933)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1185)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1173)
>           at com.example.gerobokgo.AccountFragment.openUpdateProfile(AccountFragment.java:110)
>           at com.example.gerobokgo.AccountFragment.access$000(AccountFragment.java:29)
>           at com.example.gerobokgo.AccountFragment$2.onClick(AccountFragment.java:93)

I'm having `error` on these `code`

```
// For update and pass information method
    private void openUpdateProfile() {

        Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity(), UpdateProfileFragment.class);

        //pass value from current to next page
        intent.putExtra("name",tv_name.getText().toString().trim());
        intent.putExtra("email", tv_email.getText().toString().trim());
        intent.putExtra("Home Address",tv_home.getText().toString().trim());
        intent.putExtra("Telephone", tv_phone.getText().toString().trim());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment
```

```
 //For Update Method

        btn_update.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openUpdateProfile();
            }
```

AndroidManifest

```
<application
        android:name=".Home"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".splashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    </application>
```

UpdateProfileFragment.java

```
public class UpdateProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText tv_name, tv_email, tv_home, tv_phone;
    Button btn_update;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    public UpdateProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_profile, container, false);


        //get data from intert (data from previous page)

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        String email = intent.getStringExtra("Email");
        String address = intent.getStringExtra(" Shipping Address");
        String phone = intent.getStringExtra("Telephone Number");

        //ini
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());

        tv_name = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_home = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_home);
        tv_phone = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);

        tv_name.setText(name);
        tv_email.setText(email);
        tv_home.setText(address);
        tv_phone.setText(phone);

        btn_update.setOnClickListener(this);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    private void updateProfile() {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

        String userUid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        String name = tv_name.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = tv_email.getText().toString().trim();
        String home = tv_home.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone = tv_phone.getText().toString().trim();

        Customer cust = new Customer(userUid, name, email, home, phone);
        databaseReference.child("Customer").child(userUid).setValue(cust).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getActivity().finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AccountFragment.class));


                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is `UpdateProfileFragment` activity or fragment? and did you register it in your `AndroidManifest` ?

Comment: UpdateProfileFragment is a fragment. I thought it will be auto generate???

Answer (score 0):

As per your Code **UpdateProfileFragment** is activity inside **openUpdateProfile** method.

You should declare the UpdateProfileFragment activity in **AndroidManifest** before using.

Edit:

As UpdateProfileFragment is fragment, So you are calling in wrong way fragment by startActivity(). To call fragemnt from activity do like following -

```
private void openUpdateProfile() {
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("name",tv_name.getText().toString().trim());
bundle.putString("email", tv_email.getText().toString().trim());
bundle.putString("home_address",tv_home.getText().toString().trim());
bundle.putString("telephone", tv_phone.getText().toString().trim());

UpdateProfileFragment updateFrag = new UpdateProfileFragment ();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

updateFrag.setArguments(bundle);

transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, updateFrag);
transaction.commit();

}
```

And in UpdateProfileFragment you can get data like following

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String name = getArguments().getString("name");
    String email = getArguments().getString("email");
    String address= getArguments().getString("home_address");
    String telephone= getArguments().getString("telephone");
    // rest of your code here.
    ...
    ...
```

}

NOTE: Incase of UpdateProfileFragment is fragment, no need of declare in manifest file.

Comment: should i declare it like this <activity android:name=".UpdateProfileFragment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

Comment: Yes, @lilin declare inside AndroidManifest file as you mentioned and make sure UpdateProfileFragment would be extended to Activity not fragment.

Comment: how to extend it to activity?

Comment: Can you share the code of UpdateProfileFragment ? For extend: UpdateProfileFragment extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: done. I've share it above. hopes you can help me sir :)

Comment: @lilin see my edit comment. Correct your calling way of fragment .

Comment: done but i'm having a problem with my coding after changing the UpdateProfileFragment extends Fragment to UpdateProfileFragment extends AppCompatActivity . I got error on getActivity() method

Comment: No need to extends AppCompatActivity as it is fragment.  "UpdateProfileFragment extends Fragment" is correct one.

Answer (score 0):

According to you, UpdateProfileFragment is a fragment.

So you can't call `fragment` by `startActivity()`. To call `fragemnt` from activity you have to do like following.

```
UpdateProfileFragment frag = new UpdateProfileFragment ();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,frag,"Test Fragment");
transaction.commit();
```

Also, you can pass data to `fragment` using `setArguments`

**Example:**

```
private void openUpdateProfile() {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("name",tv_name.getText().toString().trim());
    bundle.putString("email", tv_email.getText().toString().trim());
    bundle.putString("home_address",tv_home.getText().toString().trim());
    bundle.putString("telephone", tv_phone.getText().toString().trim());

    UpdateProfileFragment frag = new UpdateProfileFragment ();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    frag.setArguments(bundle);

    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,frag,"Test Fragment");
    transaction.commit();

    }
```

And in your `fragment` you can get `data` like following

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .....
        String name = this.getArguments().getString("name");
        String email = this.getArguments().getString("email");
        String address= this.getArguments().getString("home_address");
        String telephone= this.getArguments().getString("telephone");
        // rest of your code here.
        ...
        ...
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: should i declare it inside openUpdateProfile() function?

Comment: @lilin see my example section.

Comment: R.id.fragmentContainer <-- may i know where did the fragmentContainer come from?

Comment: R.id.fragmentContainer is and example. In your case, it should be in your layout (id of FrameLayout) like 

`<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">
  </FrameLayout>`